# Correctness of method - if $\{ y_n \} $ is unbounded, prove $\{ y_n z_n\} $ does not converge to $0$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, limits, alternative-proof

**Problem:** Let $c_0$ be the space of complex sequences that converge to $0$. Let $\{ y_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}   $  be a sequence of scalars such that for arbitrary sequence $\{ z_n\} \in c_0 $ we have: $ \{ y_n z_n\} \in c_0  $. Prove that $\{ y_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \in \ell_{\infty}$  .  "

I know this can be proved  using Uniform boundedness theorem, but I'm interested in proof that uses   $ ( p \implies q ) \iff  ( \lnot q \implies \lnot p) $. So, the following Statement (*) should be proved:

"If $\{ y_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \notin \ell_{\infty} $, then there exists a sequence  $\{ z_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}  \in c_0 $ such that  $\{y_n z_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}  \notin c_0 $. "   $(*)$

**My attempt:** Assume that $\{ y_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \notin \ell_{\infty}$. Hence, there is a subsequence $\{ y_{n_k} \}_{k \in \mathbb{N}}  $ which is unbounded i.e. $ \lim_{ k\rightarrow \infty} | y_{n_k}| = + \infty. $ Now, let $ z_{n_k} = \frac{1}{y_{n_k} } $. Then $\{ z_{n_k}  \}_{{k \in \mathbb{N}} }$ belongs to  $ c_0$. Can we  proceed by  evaluating limit

$  \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty  } | y_k z_{n_k} | $  and try to show it is not $0$? Can the statement ($*$) be proved like this?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Yes, this is a valid method—you would need to define $z_n$ for $n\notin\{n_k\}$, but that's not hard to do.

Comment: @GregMartin Could you please write what would be that sequence and how to prove that limit is not $0$?

Comment: Just take $z_n=0$ for $n\neq n_k.$